# Ionic Framework with Sass in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, sass, ionic-framework

I created an ionic app via the console. Afterwards I created a BlankCordova Project in Visual Studio and copied all files and folder from the ionic app into the Visual Studio project. So far everything works fine. I can debug the app with ripple and on iOS simulator on a MAC in the network.
Since I wanted to add custom styles to my app, I wanted to add Sass to my project. I used cmd to setup Sass in my project, but the changes of ionic.app.scss are not considered when debuging the app in Visual Studio. Only using the command "ionic serve" in the command line will bring the desired effect.

First of all, is there a better way setup a new ionic project by using visual studio only? Or is it the right way to create an app via the command line and integrate it in visual studio afterwards? Is it possible to change the Visual Studio debug configuration to somehow consider the scss file?

PS: I am working on Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

The SCSS files are processed by Gulp in the default Ionic solution. Look for a gulpfile.js in the root of the project. If that exists it contains a task similar to this:

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch(paths.sass, ['sass']);
});
```

This means the task will watch the path specified in the paths.sass variable for changing files and when changes are detected it will automatically start another task called 'sass'. That task is also in the file and generates the correct css files from the scss files.

You can use the Task Runner Explorer within Visual Studio to select the watch task and with right mouse button you can bind it to a "project open". This way the task will run whenever the project opens. And every change of the SCSS files will trigger a regeneration of the CSS files.

Mind that in the default Ionic project in the index.html you should uncomment the link to the generated CSS files and remove the old one. This is explained in the generated comments in the file.